# php my admin default Timestamp is wrong even if I use correct timezone

Tags: php, timestamp, default

I am experiencing problem in default timestamps I have this column name dateCreated type is TIMESTAMP and default as CURRENT_TIME whenever I insert a new row in my add member page the time generated is late for 2 hrs.

I currently live in ASIA/MANILA which is GMT +8.
I tried changing the php.ini (in my server) timezone to ASIA/MANILA.
but still the generated timestamp is late for 2hrs.

whenever I run the code echo date_default_timezone_get(); I get a result of ASIA/MANILA can somebody tell me what is the problem? and how can I FIX it? thanks in advance

Comment: did u restart httpd service?

Comment: not yet can you tell me how this is done?

Comment: better restart your server....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should restart `httpd` once. The the httpd RPM installs the /etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd Bourne script, which is accessed using the /sbin/service command.

To start your server, as root type:

`/sbin/service httpd start`

**NOTE: If you are running the Apache HTTP Server as a secure server, you will be prompted to type your password.**

To stop your server, type the command:

`/sbin/service httpd stop`

The command restart is a shorthand way of stopping and then starting your server. The restart command explicitly stops and then starts your server. You will be prompted for your password if you are running the Apache HTTP Server as a secure server. The restart command looks like the following:

`/sbin/service httpd restart`

If you just finished editing something in your httpd.conf file, you do not need to explicitly stop and start your server. Instead, you can use the reload command.

**Note: If you are running the Apache HTTP Server as a secure server, you will not need to type your password when using the reload option as the password will remain cached across reloads.**

The reload command looks like the following example:

`/sbin/service httpd reload`

By default, the httpd process will not start automatically when your machine boots. You will need to configure the httpd service to start up at boot time using an initscript utility, such as `/sbin/chkconfig`, `/sbin/ntsysv`, or the Services Configuration Tool program.

For more details about how to restart apache you can check the link [Here](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Restart+Services)

Comment: forgive me for my ignorance I am quite new to this where can I find the  /sbin/service command? in cpanel?

Comment: <?php
shell_exec('/sbin/service httpd restart');

?> is this correct?

Comment: first check Is it enable or not. I think reload work there because it can stop but not start. but you can check once. shell_exec("sudo service apache2 reload");